# I'm working on total time spent functionality

Tags: laravel

I have added start, stop pause buttons and storing time spans in db. how can i calculate timespan based on id in Laravel.
started time -2021-11-16 05:37:40 paused - 2021-11-16 05:48:40
resumed -  2021-11-16 05:52:07 stoped -2021-11-16 05:58:07

need to calculate time spans between started paused and resumed stoped and add both in Laravel 8.

Comment: What have you tried? Add your code and we will help you with problems with it. we will not write it for you

Comment: use Carbon - it have many `diff` methods - like `Carbon::make($start_time)->diff($stop_time)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use Carbon in Laravel, import it and check different methods

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

$start = Carbon::parse('2021-11-16 05:37:40');
$paused = Carbon::parse('2021-11-16 05:48:40');
        

$difference = $paused->diffInMinutes($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInDays($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInHours($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInMicroseconds($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInMinutes($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInMonths($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInQuarters($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInSeconds($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInWeekdays($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInWeekendDays($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInWeeks($start);
$difference = $paused->diffInYears($start);
$difference = $paused->diffAsCarbonInterval($start);
$difference = $paused->diffForHumans($start);

echo $difference;
        
$resumed = Carbon::parse('2021-11-16 05:52:07');
$stopped = Carbon::parse('2021-11-16 05:58:07');

//do the same with $resumed and $stopped like in example I did it with $start and $paused
```

Comment: only answer when the question asker has attempted, see stackoverflow guidelines